# Getting multiple check box results in POST with php

Tags: php

Hi i have a form that send across a single check box, which is working perfect, however when i add a second tick box, the second one doesn't seem to pass any information.  The first one works but the second one doesn't.

Below is my code, any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Form Side

```
"<input type='checkbox' name='ip[]' value='$row[ip]'/>";
"<input type='checkbox' name='in[]' value='$row[ip]'/>";
```

add Side

```
$ip_array = isset($_POST['ip']) && is_array($_POST['ip']) ? $_POST['ip'] : array();
foreach( $ip_array as $ip ) {

$in_array = isset($_POST['in']) && is_array($_POST['in']) ? $_POST['in'] : array();
foreach( $in_array as $in ) {
```

The top part of the code seems tocatch the checkbox fine but the bottom one doesn't.

Comment: You need to check all checkbox before send, unchecked input doesnt send. Make sure that all checkboxes checked before send

Comment: Thanks, i have yes they are both set but still no results

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see what's going on? Ideally this would be using a proper debugger (xDebug, ZendDebugger etc) possibly via an IDE but if you don't have those tools have you tried echoing var_dump( $_POST ); to see what's in $_POST when you submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code below to get the inputs for checkbox:

```
<?php
$var1 = $_POST["ip"];
$var2 = $_POST["in"];
if(is_array($var1))
{
    if(sizeof($var1) > 0)
    {
        foreach($var1 as $i)
        {
            echo $i;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No value selected in ip";
    }
}

if(is_array($var2))
{
    if(sizeof($var2) > 0)
    {
        foreach($var2 as $i)
        {
            echo $i;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No value selected in";
    }
}
?>
```